# Data inside the string became unusable in python

Tags: python

I put a number into a file, but the next time I opened it with the Open() command, I put the number inside it, which was string, into a variable int() but the number was gone!!!

```
file = open('times.txt', 'r')  # wrong = 4
print(file.read())  # wrong = 4
wrong = list(file.read())  # there is a problem, when is str not problem but if int => wrong = 0
print(wrong)  # wrong = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you call `read()` on `file` for the first time the cursor is set to the end of the file.

Should you want to read the contents of file again you can use [seek](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm):

```
file.seek(0)
```

Which will return you to the beginning of the file.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that saving the output in a variable is probably best if they plan on reading the content multiple times anyway (unless they expect the file to be huge).